# Trading Cards & Packs - compute the hypothetical number of packs to purchase to achieve a certain probability to complete a certain Cards' set

Tags: probability, hypergeometric-function, coupon-collector

I'm trying to solve a probability problem within the context of a Trading Cards game, but I'm not sure if using Hypergeometric Distribution is the right way.

Given the following conditions:

- Given a population size of **N=1500** cards: 5 different Team Cards x 10 copies x 30 Teams
- To win the game, a user needs to collect all **m=5** Cards of a chosen Team (e.g. Team A)
- User can buy only packs of 5 Cards per time (**n=5** permitted draws)
- Packs have no duplicated cards.
- Cards are equally distributed across Packs.

By using the Excel Formula:
`=HYPGEOMDIST(k,n,m,N)`
the probability to pick 1 Team card by purchasing **k=1** Pack should be `14.59%`

By making the product of the probabilities, the probability to complete a set of 5 team cards by purchasing 5 Packs should be `14.59%^5 = 0.01%`

If all above is correct, I'm still wondering **how to find the number of packs I would need to buy, given a certain target p probability to complete the set**. E.g. If I wanted a target p = 50% or p = 99% or p = 100% probability of completing the m = 5 Cards Team set, how many packs shall I buy?

I'm adding here the excel with the data, hope it helps! https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1B-sRhDB_DGmPbGpL-4BD0fzVPJ01dUMlD950seoGMk4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: My understanding of this question is that there are $50$ cards for each team: $10$ cards bearing each of the $5$ different card designs for the team.  Collecting all the cards for a team means acquiring at least one card with each of the team's designs.  But what does "packs have no duplicated cards" mean?  Does it mean no two cards with the same design, or no two cards at all for the same team?

Comment: In either case, the hypergeometric distribution isn't correct, as it doesn't take this "no duplicated cards" constraint into account.

Comment: And moreover, raising the probability of success with one pack to the 5th power isn't correct either.  You could "succeed" (get a card for the correct team) with each of the first five packs, but unless each "success" was a different design, you wouldn't have collected all the designs yet.  (Not even to mention that the draws aren't independent.)